# Windows Azure - restricting the IP address rage to access a WebRole

Tags: azure

Is it possible to restrict the access to a Azure WebRole to a list of IP ranges.
I saw there are a number of articles explaining how to configure the firewall for accessing an SQL Azure instance but what about the WebRoles / WorkerRoles?

Thank you,
Luc

Answer (score 2):

Since V1.3 of the SDK (and now V1.4), full IIS support and Startup tasks have been available to help solve this issue.

I've blogged about this http://blog.bareweb.eu/2011/04/restricting-access-by-ip-in-azure-web-role-v1-4/

You can use ipSecurity in web.config, but you must also do some work regarding installing the IPSec module into IIS.

Regards
Andy

Comment: This answer is pretty obsolete now, see Henri's answer below for more up-to-date and easier solution.

Answer (score 2):

Since Azure SDK 2.4 there has been a possibility to use **Access Control List** (ACL) to apply IP restrictions for your cloud services. I wrote a blog post on this: http://www.henrihietala.fi/apply-ip-restrictions-for-azure-cloud-service/

Just add the ACL in your **ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="MyWebRole.Azure" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="4" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2014-06.2.4">
  <Role name="MyWebRole">
    ...
  </Role>
  <NetworkConfiguration>
    <AccessControls>
      <AccessControl name="ipRestrictions">
        <Rule action="permit" description="allowed-edu" order="100" remoteSubnet="137.133.228.111/32" />
        <Rule action="permit" description="allowed-test" order="101" remoteSubnet="168.61.66.2/32" />
        <Rule action="permit" description="allowed-prod" order="102" remoteSubnet="168.61.66.131/32" />
        <Rule action="deny" description="Others" order="800" remoteSubnet="0.0.0.0/0" />
      </AccessControl>
    </AccessControls>
    <EndpointAcls>
      <EndpointAcl role="MyWebRole" endPoint="Endpoint1" accessControl="ipRestrictions" />
      <EndpointAcl role="MyWebRole" endPoint="HttpsIn" accessControl="ipRestrictions" />
    </EndpointAcls>
  </NetworkConfiguration>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

Be careful with rule attributes. Your deployment will fail if you have specified the same order number or description twice or the IP address in `remoteSubnet` is incorrect.

Comment: Did you ever find any more official documentation? I would like to know what the expected result of this is (ie. status returns)

Answer (score 1):

I have not personally done this in Azure yet, but have you tried just using the IIS7 IP security feature via [the `system.webServer/security/ipSecurity` configuration element](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/ipSecurity)?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer, Drew.
The moderator on this post states "ipSecurity doesn't work on Windows Azure currently." 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/c197f725-503e-4a44-abce-ea99c741758d/

And using the config file won't work for me as I want to add/remove IP ranges without having to redeploy the whole package!
This is a check that should be run before the traffic reaches the application.
I can't believe such an important feature is being left out as I cannot see an LOB application not wanting to restrict the traffic!
Luc

Comment: Ah, sorry I should have done more investigating before suggesting it. Well at least it's here for posterity's sake and will hopefully help people who look at this topic understand it's *not* an option.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides the recipe for doing this in this May 2012 article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj154098.aspx.

> You can restrict a Windows Azure web role access to a set of specified IP addresses by modifying your IIS web.config file and creating a command file which unlocks the ipSecurity section of the ApplicationHost.config file.